# How can I change a value in a column if that line contains a specific word using sed/awk or bash while keeping the whitespacing?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, pdb

I have a pdb that looks like:

```
ATOM      1  P     A 2   1     224.160 179.728 151.662  1.00 40.00           P  
ATOM      2  OP1   A 2   1     225.507 179.132 151.738  1.00 40.00           O  
ATOM      3  CA    A 2   1     223.640 180.497 152.816  1.00 40.00           O  
ATOM      4  O5'   A 2   1     224.374 180.738 150.465  1.00 40.00           O
```

I want to change the 11th column to 1.0000 if a line contains atom CA and save these changes in the same file.

How can I do that using sed, awk or bash so that I keep the same spacing between the columns?
Thank you

Comment: Please do mention your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Well I used awk '$1=="CA4"{$4="1.0000"}1' file, but I do not get the same space between the columns. I am not sure how to obtain exact same spacing in between.

Comment: I managed to do it with sed, but in case someone is willing to write how to do it with bash and/or awk I would be grateful! Thank you

Comment: What does it mean to `keep the same spacing between the columns` when you're changing the width of a field? Should `foo<blank><blank>40.00<blank><blank>bar` become `foo<blank><blank>1.00000<blank><blank>bar` or `foo<blank>1.00000<blank><blank>bar` or `foo<blank><blank>1.00000<blank>bar` or something else? [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239218/replace-a-column-and-preserve-spacing

Answer (score 0):

Awk will do the job.

```
awk '$1  == "ATOM" && $3 == "CA" { $11 = 1.0 } { print }' <infile > outfile
```

Google `awk` for more information, as this is a basic tool worth learning

Assuming fixed width columns, as per comment below, the awk script can be modified to specify FIELDWIDTHS. The values need to be checked, as question not clear about exact widths.

```
awk -v 'FIELDWIDTHS=4 8 6 4 1 6 9 9 9 6 5 12' '
$1  == "ATOM" && $3 == "CA" { $11 = 1.0 }
{ print }
'
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I keep the same spacing between the columns?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PDB format. Looks like space separated, but I'm not sure. What are the requirements - how fields are defined ?

Comment: ATOM      3  CA    A 2   1     223.640 180.497 152.816  1.00 40.00           O

Basically, in python I would have the following parsing:

 if line.startswith("ATOM"):
                atom_id = line[4:11].strip()
                atom_type = line[11:16].strip()
                resname = line[17:20].strip()
                chain = line[21]
                res_id = line[22:27].strip()
                Cartn_x = float(line[30:38])
                Cartn_y = float(line[38:46])
                Cartn_z = float(line[46:54]) etc. 

I just do not know what would be equivalent to awk. :)

Comment: Consider posting the comment about the format of the file. It's not common nowadays to have fixed width data files. Most answers assume space separate files. Also, it helps a lot of you post sample output.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -E '/ CA /s/[^ ]+/1.000/11' file`

(GNU sed, assuming spaces and not tabs)

This uses `11` after the replacement to replace the 11th word.  The replacement only happens on lines matching `/ CA /`

`-E` is required for the `+` to work as intended.

You may want to tailor the whitespace or replacement string to your exact requirements.  Since's it's only affecting the 11th column, you can do exactly whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask in case you would have tabs, what would change in the command?

Comment: Something like this `sed -E '/[[:space:]]CA[[:space:]]/s/[^[:space:]]+/1.0000/11' ` -- seems to work if I make your sample tab separated.

Answer (score 0):

The following **sed** command(s) will work:

```
sed '/ CA /s/\([^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+\)....../\11.0000/'
```

or:

```
sed -E '/ CA /s/([^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +)....../\11.0000/'
```

or (with bash):

```
X="[^ ]+ +"; sed -E "/ CA /s/($X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X)....../\11.0000/"
```

or:

```
X="[^ ]\+ \+"; sed "/ CA /s/\($X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X\)....../\11.0000/"
```

to give:

```
ATOM      1  P     A 2   1     224.160 179.728 151.662  1.00 40.00           P  
ATOM      2  OP1   A 2   1     225.507 179.132 151.738  1.00 40.00           O  
ATOM      3  CA    A 2   1     223.640 180.497 152.816  1.00 1.0000          O  
ATOM      4  O5'   A 2   1     224.374 180.738 150.465  1.00 40.00           O
```

**Explanation:**

- `/ CA /` if a line contains the token "CA", then
- `s/($X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X)....../` replace the first ten columns and the first six characters of the 11th column by
- `\11.0000/` what was already in the ten columns, and by "1.0000" in the 11th.

**Refinements:**

- This assumes the "CA" is not at the start of the *first* column; this can be fixed using `/\<CA\>/`.
- If there are tabs, replace spaces in the above with `[[:space]]`.
- The above fails if the existing 11th column has more than six non-blank characters. If you *know* in advance that it has say at most eight characters, add two extra dots to `......` and two spaces after the "1.0000".
- Otherwise, you can first reduce the 11th column to a single non-blank character by running:

  ```
  X="[^ ]\+ \+"; sed "/ CA /{:a;s/\($X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X$X\)\([^ ]\+\)[^ ] /\1\2  /;ta}"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that the 11th column is always 16 characters wide, the following **sed** command:

```
sed '/ CA /s/[^ ]\+ \+/1.0000          /11'
```

will give:

```
ATOM      1  P     A 2   1     224.160 179.728 151.662  1.00 40.00           P  
ATOM      2  OP1   A 2   1     225.507 179.132 151.738  1.00 40.00           O  
ATOM      3  CA    A 2   1     223.640 180.497 152.816  1.00 1.0000          O  
ATOM      4  O5'   A 2   1     224.374 180.738 150.465  1.00 40.00           O
```

Explanation: On lines with the token `CA`, this replaces the 11th column with `1.0000` followed by 10 spaces.

With some versions of **sed**, you may need to replace `\+` with `\{1,\}`, as in:

```
sed '/ CA /s/[^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}/1.0000          /11'
```

---

Alternatively, if you know that the 11th column always begins at the 62nd character and is 16 characters wide, the following will also work:

```
sed -i '/ CA /s/\(.\{61\}\).\{16\}/\11.0000          /' filename
```

Explanation:

- On lines with the token "CA", `/ CA /`
- Capture the first 61 characters with `\(.\{61\}\)`, and keep them with `\1`
- And replace the next 16 characters, `.\{16\}`, with `1.0000` followed by 10 spaces.
- The `-i` switch modifies the file in place.